# JQUERY each(), determining the # of matches so you can only act on the last one

Tags: jquery, each

When using JQUERY.each(), what is the way to obtain the value of matched items. I'd like to wrap an IF inside the each() to only act on the last match. thx

Comment: Why don't you use `:last` selector? http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: With Each, I don't think that makes sense?

Comment: He's saying the `.each()` isn't necessary if all you want to operate on is that last element.

Answer (score 4):

That seems wasteful. Instead, just select the [last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) item and act on it. E.g.:

```
$("td:last").hide();
$("p:last").hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

The [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method tells you which index item you are currently working with.

```
$.each(myItems, function(index, value) { 
    if(index == myItems.length-1)
        doStuff(value);
});
```

It might be easier to just index the last item like so:

```
doStuff(myItems[myItems.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using each you can use `:last` if you only want to get the last item of your DOM elements for example

```
 <ul class="myUls">
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

in you script, you can say

```
var last = $('.myUls li:last');
```

the DOM of the last would be the `<li>three</li>`

moreover if you want to select an index of an array of DOM element you can use :eq() say for example above you want to select the DOM `<li>two</li>` you can do.

```
var two = $('.myUls li:eq(1)');
```

that will get you the two as `<li>two</li>`

Answer (score 0):

As BrunoLM mentions, you should probably just use the `:last` selector.

If you do want to know the number of matches for whatever other reason, you can use `.size()`, or `.length`

e.g.

```
$("b").each(function(i) {
  if (i == $("b").size() - 1) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:last` selector. In general though, if you want to know the position of the element you're iterating over with `.each()` it gets passed to the callback.

```
$('.selector').each(function(index, elem) {
    //index gets the position of the current elem
});
```